# Google Drive API PHP: Files.get returns null value

Tags: php, api, google-drive-api

I am creating an application that integrates with Google Drive API (version 3) in order for it to find a file inside a named folder by way of user input and then to get the web content link for that file. My application is contacting a service account where my application's files will be stored and getting the link. The only problem is when I use the code shown below, it returns the output shown below which is all NULL except for a few fields. What am I doing wrong?

**Code that is causing the problem:**

```
<?php

    require_once("./vendor/autoload.php");

    putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=service-account.json');

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
    $client->setScopes(implode(' ', array(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE)));

    $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

$optParams = array("q" => "'0BxNR85wn9MERczRqbkU0LTBQdUk' in parents");
$results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);
if(count($results->getFiles()) == 0){
    echo "No files found.";
}else{
    echo "Files found.<br>";
    foreach($results->getFiles() as $file){
if($file->getId() != "0B4C3vGWHN-Wgc3RhcnRlcl9maWxl"){
echo $file->getId() . "<br>";
        $content = $service->files->get($file->getId());
        $filedata = $service->files->get($file->getId());
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($filedata);
        echo "</pre>";
}
    }
}
?>
```

**The codes output:**

```
Files found.
1L61iP4mrc0HyVmHhLB4TFz-1revFg2l6cdPQDh7OLUY
object(Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile)#68 (56) {
  ["collection_key":protected]=>
  string(6) "spaces"
  ["appProperties"]=>
  NULL
  ["capabilitiesType":protected]=>
  string(42) "Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileCapabilities"
  ["capabilitiesDataType":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["contentHintsType":protected]=>
  string(42) "Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileContentHints"
  ["contentHintsDataType":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["createdTime"]=>
  NULL
  ["description"]=>
  NULL
  ["explicitlyTrashed"]=>
  NULL
  ["fileExtension"]=>
  NULL
  ["folderColorRgb"]=>
  NULL
  ["fullFileExtension"]=>
  NULL
  ["headRevisionId"]=>
  NULL
  ["iconLink"]=>
  NULL
  ["id"]=>
  string(44) "1L61iP4mrc0HyVmHhLB4TFz-1revFg2l6cdPQDh7OLUY"
  ["imageMediaMetadataType":protected]=>
  string(48) "Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileImageMediaMetadata"
  ["imageMediaMetadataDataType":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["isAppAuthorized"]=>
  NULL
  ["kind"]=>
  string(10) "drive#file"
  ["lastModifyingUserType":protected]=>
  string(25) "Google_Service_Drive_User"
  ["lastModifyingUserDataType":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["md5Checksum"]=>
  NULL
  ["mimeType"]=>
  string(36) "application/vnd.google-apps.document"
  ["modifiedByMeTime"]=>
  NULL
  ["modifiedTime"]=>
  NULL
  ["name"]=>
  string(17) "Untitled document"
  ["originalFilename"]=>
  NULL
  ["ownedByMe"]=>
  NULL
  ["ownersType":protected]=>
  string(25) "Google_Service_Drive_User"
  ["ownersDataType":protected]=>
  string(5) "array"
  ["parents"]=>
  NULL
  ["permissionsType":protected]=>
  string(31) "Google_Service_Drive_Permission"
  ["permissionsDataType":protected]=>
  string(5) "array"
  ["properties"]=>
  NULL
  ["quotaBytesUsed"]=>
  NULL
  ["shared"]=>
  NULL
  ["sharedWithMeTime"]=>
  NULL
  ["sharingUserType":protected]=>
  string(25) "Google_Service_Drive_User"
  ["sharingUserDataType":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["size"]=>
  NULL
  ["spaces"]=>
  NULL
  ["starred"]=>
  NULL
  ["thumbnailLink"]=>
  NULL
  ["trashed"]=>
  NULL
  ["version"]=>
  NULL
  ["videoMediaMetadataType":protected]=>
  string(48) "Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileVideoMediaMetadata"
  ["videoMediaMetadataDataType":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["viewedByMe"]=>
  NULL
  ["viewedByMeTime"]=>
  NULL
  ["viewersCanCopyContent"]=>
  NULL
  ["webContentLink"]=>
  NULL
  ["webViewLink"]=>
  NULL
  ["writersCanShare"]=>
  NULL
  ["internal_gapi_mappings":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["modelData":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["processed":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
0BxNR85wn9MERUjRaYURVdXVhMlk
object(Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile)#79 (56) {
  ["collection_key":protected]=>
  string(6) "spaces"
  ["appProperties"]=>
  NULL
  ["capabilitiesType":protected]=>
  string(42) "Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileCapabilities"
  ["capabilitiesDataType":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["contentHintsType":protected]=>
  string(42) "Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileContentHints"
  ["contentHintsDataType":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["createdTime"]=>
  NULL
  ["description"]=>
  NULL
  ["explicitlyTrashed"]=>
  NULL
  ["fileExtension"]=>
  NULL
  ["folderColorRgb"]=>
  NULL
  ["fullFileExtension"]=>
  NULL
  ["headRevisionId"]=>
  NULL
  ["iconLink"]=>
  NULL
  ["id"]=>
  string(28) "0BxNR85wn9MERUjRaYURVdXVhMlk"
  ["imageMediaMetadataType":protected]=>
  string(48) "Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileImageMediaMetadata"
  ["imageMediaMetadataDataType":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["isAppAuthorized"]=>
  NULL
  ["kind"]=>
  string(10) "drive#file"
  ["lastModifyingUserType":protected]=>
  string(25) "Google_Service_Drive_User"
  ["lastModifyingUserDataType":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["md5Checksum"]=>
  NULL
  ["mimeType"]=>
  string(10) "image/jpeg"
  ["modifiedByMeTime"]=>
  NULL
  ["modifiedTime"]=>
  NULL
  ["name"]=>
  string(76) "Copy of 3f86195896e5d28d5e9492eb0415544049c4a49467d3534d3fa2e5d52a2636e0.jpg"
  ["originalFilename"]=>
  NULL
  ["ownedByMe"]=>
  NULL
  ["ownersType":protected]=>
  string(25) "Google_Service_Drive_User"
  ["ownersDataType":protected]=>
  string(5) "array"
  ["parents"]=>
  NULL
  ["permissionsType":protected]=>
  string(31) "Google_Service_Drive_Permission"
  ["permissionsDataType":protected]=>
  string(5) "array"
  ["properties"]=>
  NULL
  ["quotaBytesUsed"]=>
  NULL
  ["shared"]=>
  NULL
  ["sharedWithMeTime"]=>
  NULL
  ["sharingUserType":protected]=>
  string(25) "Google_Service_Drive_User"
  ["sharingUserDataType":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["size"]=>
  NULL
  ["spaces"]=>
  NULL
  ["starred"]=>
  NULL
  ["thumbnailLink"]=>
  NULL
  ["trashed"]=>
  NULL
  ["version"]=>
  NULL
  ["videoMediaMetadataType":protected]=>
  string(48) "Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileVideoMediaMetadata"
  ["videoMediaMetadataDataType":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["viewedByMe"]=>
  NULL
  ["viewedByMeTime"]=>
  NULL
  ["viewersCanCopyContent"]=>
  NULL
  ["webContentLink"]=>
  NULL
  ["webViewLink"]=>
  NULL
  ["writersCanShare"]=>
  NULL
  ["internal_gapi_mappings":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["modelData":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["processed":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
0BxNR85wn9MERWUR1TEh6ckROUGM
object(Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile)#74 (56) {
  ["collection_key":protected]=>
  string(6) "spaces"
  ["appProperties"]=>
  NULL
  ["capabilitiesType":protected]=>
  string(42) "Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileCapabilities"
  ["capabilitiesDataType":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["contentHintsType":protected]=>
  string(42) "Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileContentHints"
  ["contentHintsDataType":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["createdTime"]=>
  NULL
  ["description"]=>
  NULL
  ["explicitlyTrashed"]=>
  NULL
  ["fileExtension"]=>
  NULL
  ["folderColorRgb"]=>
  NULL
  ["fullFileExtension"]=>
  NULL
  ["headRevisionId"]=>
  NULL
  ["iconLink"]=>
  NULL
  ["id"]=>
  string(28) "0BxNR85wn9MERWUR1TEh6ckROUGM"
  ["imageMediaMetadataType":protected]=>
  string(48) "Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileImageMediaMetadata"
  ["imageMediaMetadataDataType":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["isAppAuthorized"]=>
  NULL
  ["kind"]=>
  string(10) "drive#file"
  ["lastModifyingUserType":protected]=>
  string(25) "Google_Service_Drive_User"
  ["lastModifyingUserDataType":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["md5Checksum"]=>
  NULL
  ["mimeType"]=>
  string(10) "image/jpeg"
  ["modifiedByMeTime"]=>
  NULL
  ["modifiedTime"]=>
  NULL
  ["name"]=>
  string(68) "3f86195896e5d28d5e9492eb0415544049c4a49467d3534d3fa2e5d52a2636e0.jpg"
  ["originalFilename"]=>
  NULL
  ["ownedByMe"]=>
  NULL
  ["ownersType":protected]=>
  string(25) "Google_Service_Drive_User"
  ["ownersDataType":protected]=>
  string(5) "array"
  ["parents"]=>
  NULL
  ["permissionsType":protected]=>
  string(31) "Google_Service_Drive_Permission"
  ["permissionsDataType":protected]=>
  string(5) "array"
  ["properties"]=>
  NULL
  ["quotaBytesUsed"]=>
  NULL
  ["shared"]=>
  NULL
  ["sharedWithMeTime"]=>
  NULL
  ["sharingUserType":protected]=>
  string(25) "Google_Service_Drive_User"
  ["sharingUserDataType":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["size"]=>
  NULL
  ["spaces"]=>
  NULL
  ["starred"]=>
  NULL
  ["thumbnailLink"]=>
  NULL
  ["trashed"]=>
  NULL
  ["version"]=>
  NULL
  ["videoMediaMetadataType":protected]=>
  string(48) "Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileVideoMediaMetadata"
  ["videoMediaMetadataDataType":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["viewedByMe"]=>
  NULL
  ["viewedByMeTime"]=>
  NULL
  ["viewersCanCopyContent"]=>
  NULL
  ["webContentLink"]=>
  NULL
  ["webViewLink"]=>
  NULL
  ["writersCanShare"]=>
  NULL
  ["internal_gapi_mappings":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["modelData":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["processed":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

Right now it is just a bunch of test code to see what that files get method is going to return, which at the moment is a lot of null, so right now don't expect much functionality. The code below isn't supposed to download anything yet, it's just the debugging. So, what I need to know is, how can I access the webContentLink property of the 3 files this application has found from the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please [read](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration) this Drive API V3 migration documentation.

> Full resources are no longer returned by default. Use the fields query parameter to request specific fields to be returned. If left unspecified only a subset of commonly used fields are returned.

Comment: So, how do I add this fields property to the Files.get method?

Comment: Please refer the PHP quick start page : https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/php

Comment: Okay. Thank you. Tonight I will try it out and I am sure it will work. If it does I will mark this as the answer. Thank you. If it works I will set it as the answer

Comment: That perfectly solved my problem. Thanks for you hard work.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be a little more specific, the `$service->files->get()` call can take a 2nd parameter with the list of fields you'd like returned. e.g. to just check the trashed flag for a file or folder you could use:

```
$optParams = array('fields' => 'trashed');
$filedata = $service->files->get($file->getId(),$optParams);

if ($filedata->getTrashed()) {
  // The file or folder was trashed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late, but I hope I will help someone.
I am using Drive V2, I will demonstrate using a small sample where I fetch details of a single file by id.

First Share your Drive account's folder to your service account.
Your service account's addresss looks like XXX@XXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com.
Then your service account can see the shared folder from your Drive account.

-> Ensure you include fields that you want displayed

-> Also check on permissions

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('client_id.json');
//$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));

$driveService = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

$fileId='1gYCx2d_pmAgfPNQSR1O0cfGied';
$response = $driveService->files->get($fileId, array(
    //'pageSize' => 10,
    'fields' => 'id, description,webViewLink,webContentLink,properties',        
    //'alt' => 'media'
));
header('Content-Type: application/json'); //to beautify view in browser
echo json_encode($response);
```

Response

```
appProperties   null
copyRequiresWriterPermission    null
createdTime null
description "This is an audio of a recorded call"
explicitlyTrashed   null
fileExtension   null
folderColorRgb  null
fullFileExtension   null
hasAugmentedPermissions null
hasThumbnail    null
headRevisionId  null
iconLink    null
id  "1gYCx2d_pmAgfPNQSRxZcSnv1O0cfGied"
isAppAuthorized null
kind    null
md5Checksum null
mimeType    null
modifiedByMe    null
modifiedByMeTime    null
modifiedTime    null
name    null
originalFilename    null
ownedByMe   null
parents null
permissionIds   null
properties  
filepath    "/2018-10-25/call_09-59-41_OUT_100.amr"
date    "1540450781384"
recording_duration  "14900"
phonenumber "100"
version "2.0"
duration    "0:14"
calltype    "1"
comment_subject "100"
quotaBytesUsed  null
shared  null
sharedWithMeTime    null
size    null
spaces  null
starred null
teamDriveId null
thumbnailLink   null
thumbnailVersion    null
trashed null
trashedTime null
version null
viewedByMe  null
viewedByMeTime  null
viewersCanCopyContent   null
webContentLink  "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1gYCx2d_pmAgfPNQSRxZcSnv1O0cfGied&export=download"
webViewLink "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gYCx2d_pmAgfPNQSRxZcSnv1O0cfGied/view?usp=drivesdk"
writersCanShare null
```